# Drop until the last occurence of a pattern in Haskell

Tags: haskell

[`dropWhile`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v:dropWhile) asks for a predicate and removes an element from a list one by one until predicate is false for the first time, then it just returns what's left. For example you could remove elements from a list of strings until you find a string that starts with a slash:

```
> dropWhile (not . isPrefixOf "/") ["a", "b", "/c", "d"]
["/c","d"]
```

But what if you want to continuously delete elements until you match a pattern for the last time? For example, Python's [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) accepts arbitrary number of string parameters. If any parameter starts with a slash, all previous are ignored, and the remaining are joined with a separator:

```
>>> os.path.join("a", "/b", "c", "/d", "e")
'/d/e'
```

How do I continuously drop elements from a list until some condition is met for the last time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`groupBy`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v:groupBy) allows to group elements of a list based on a predicate that somehow compares each two near elements. Every time predicate fails, the new group is started. So to group elements by each occurrence of a slash prefix, every time the string starts with a slash, we should start a new group, therefore the predicate must fail:

```
> groupBy (\x y -> not $ isPrefixOf "/" y) ["a", "/b", "c", "/d", "e"]
[["a"],["/b","c"],["/d","e"]]
```

The general version, therefore, must look like this:

```
dropUntilLast :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
dropUntilLast f = last . groupBy (\x y -> not $ f y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Data.List (groupBy)

removeTilLast :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
removeTilLast p = last . groupBy (const $ not . p)
```

[groupBy](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-2.15/base-4.7.0.2/Data-List.html#v:groupBy)